# SSH command not working properly when trying to find & delete text to fix WP malware

Tags: php, wordpress, ssh

Unfortunately I need to clean up WordPress installations which were hit with a malware attack from either a plugin or being out of date, but being a total SSH beginner I've found it difficult to see exactly what I'm doing wrong.

The code that I need to delete is this:

```
<?php $qiorgeq = '22)gj!|!*nbsbq%)323ldfidk! (...base64 text...) ?>
```

Since I need to delete that from all files which began with a php tag on my server I thought that this would do the trick:

```
find -type f -name '*.php' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's#<?php $qiorgeq*?>##g'
```

Came to this conclusion after several failed attempts and many errors. This seems to **run** but seems to have done nothing and has not deleted anything.

I feel like the answer is close... please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things here:

**`find`** 
First argument for `find` should be a directory to search.
Ex: `find . -type f -name *.php -print0` (mind the `.` between `find` and `-name`)

**`sed`**
By default sed does not modify the content of a file. It outputs the result to the standard output. Adding `-i "myextension"` will save the modified file to `yourfile.php.myextension` but still not modify the source file.
To overwrite the source file, what you need to do is `sed -i "" 's#search#replace#g` (add an empty string after the `-i` option)

**Regexp**
You should use `.*` in your `sed` regular expression rather than `*`. (The `.` character matches any character). Your current regular expression will only match `qiorge` + any number of `q`.

**Finally**, a working command would be:
`find . -type f -name '*.php' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i "" 's#<?php $qiorgeq.*?>##g'`

Edit 1: The command works on Mac OS but `sed` may differ on Linux.
This command may work on Linux: `find . -type f -name '*.php' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's#<?php $qiorgeq.*?>##g'` (I removed the empty string after the `-i` parameter)

Edit 2:
The following script will list the infected files (works with newlines, works with files containing spaces):

```
find . -iname "*.php" | while read f
do
    if [[ "$( grep "<?php $qiorgeq" "$f" )" != "" ]] ; then
        echo "$f"
    fi
done
```

You could replace the `echo` by any processing you wish.

Oneliner: `find . -iname "*.php" | while read f ; do if [[ "$( grep "<?php $qiorgeq" "$f" )" != "" ]] ; then echo $f ; fi ; done`

Comment: Note: This does not work if the content you replaced with `(...base64 text...)` contains a line return.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to respond and for breaking down what I missed. Unfortunately, when I tried this command I get this:

`sed: can't reads s#<?php $qiorgeq.*?>##g: No such file or directory`

Comment: Ah. The Mac version of `sed` (the one I used) might behave differently from the Linux one. Try the remove the empty string I was talking about after the '-i' parameter.

Comment: I wondered what the "" was for, but didn't want to mess around with something that could have a huge impact on my files. Important thing is that the command **WORKED** and I am so grateful for your solution! This has helped me immensely and I really appreciate you taking the time to write such a detailed explanation!!

Comment: Bash scripting is very powerful for this kind of things but when you're new to it, it's a bit hard to know it which direction to go. When you're used to it, you've done the same mistakes hundreds of times so it's easy to find what's wrong. It didn't take too long for me to write my answer :) The only thing here is that I have to remember that Mac OS commands don't behave exactly the same as Linux ones.